# Mongodb driver not loading on php

Tags: php, mongodb, database-connection

I am trying to install **MongoDB** drivers on my **PHP Server**.

I am running **PHP 5.4.22** and I have added `php_mongodb.dll` to the ext folder of php and restarted my apache service. I have added `extension=php_mongodb.dll` to my **php.ini** file.

The version of **MongoDB** driver is supposed to be working with my php driver (*php_mongo-1.6.8-5.4-vc9.dll*)

I have read numerous posts and how-to's on the subject but simply *can't* get it to work.

Please help!

Comment: Please include details about what doesn't work. You say you can't get it to work, but what troubles are you experiencing? What do you expect to happen and what happens instead?

Comment: I expected it to load but it did not. As stated in the answer below I already fixed it.

Comment: What I meant is that you didn't describe how "didn't load" manifested itself exactly (error message? etc.). Anyway, if you fixed it please accept your own answer. (Sorry I didn't see the answer because I was commenting from the review queue where you are only shown the question and comments on it, not the answer.)

Comment: No problem, I understand. I will accept my answer as the solution when I am able to (obligatory wait for 2 days before accepting own answer).

Comment: Right, never mind, I forgot this limitation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After updating PHP from 5.4.22 to 5.6.20 and switching the mongo.dll driver to the correct version it started working.

Nothing else has changed, only the PHP version and its corresponding driver.